# I cant create h2 database before tests, but after first test other tests work fine

Tags: java, h2

i am trying to make my tests on h2 database. But my first test always falling with error

```
nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcBadGrammarException: [90079] [90079] Schema "DEF" not found; SQL statement:
```

although other tests for fine.

For making database i use @BeforeEach annotation
here code:

```
 String sql =
                /*"DROP SCHEMA DEF;\n" +*/
                "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DEF; \n " +
                        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.definition ();\n" +
                        "ALTER TABLE def.definition ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS id  varchar NOT NULL ;\n" +
                        "ALTER TABLE def.definition ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS path varchar NOT NULL default NULL;\n" +
                        "ALTER TABLE def.definition ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS name varchar NULL;\n" +
                        "ALTER TABLE def.definition ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS description varchar NULL;\n" +
                        "ALTER TABLE def.definition ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS type varchar NULL;\n" +
                        "ALTER TABLE def.definition ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS \"schema\" json NULL;\n" +
                        "ALTER TABLE def.definition ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS definition_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);\n" +
                        "ALTER TABLE def.definition ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS definition_un UNIQUE (path);\n" +
                        "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS definition_name_idx ON def.definition (name);\n" +
                        "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS definition_description_idx ON def.definition (description);";

        Mono<Integer> integerMono = databaseClient.sql(sql)
                .fetch()
                .rowsUpdated();

        StepVerifier.create(integerMono)
                .expectNextCount(1)
                .verifyComplete();
```

I tried rewriting sql code, or using another sql dialect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i found new way of executing sql before tests:

```
Mono.from(connectionFactory.create())
    .map(
        c -> {
          ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(c, new ClassPathResource("scripts/create.sql"))
              .subscribe();
          return "123";
        })
    .subscribe();
```

Here u create connection from your connection factory, then using sql file(in my case it is create.sql at scripts package at resources),execute your sql script